# How to show related products in product view page with magento?

Tags: magento

I want to show related products in product view page after short description.
I added the below code in app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/layout/catalog.xml page

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/> `under <reference name="content">` section.
```

and comment the below code

```
 <reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

after that i made one related.phtml page and put it in `app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalod/product/list/`section.
and call this related.phtml page in `app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalod/product/view.phtml` page by writing this code   `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related'); ?>`.also cache is cleared.then also it is unable to call the page
If anyone knows this,please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Hi i have custom code's to get the related products and you can add this code where you want to show the related products

```
<?php
foreach ($_product->getRelatedLinkCollection() as $link) {
$dats= $link->getLinkedProductId();
}
if($dats)
{
?>
<div class="block block-related">
<div class="block-title">
<strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Related Products') ?></span></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
<ol class="mini-products-list" id="block-related">
<?php $bk=1;
foreach ($_product->getRelatedLinkCollection() as $link) {
if($bk=='4'){ break; }
else{
$relatedData[$link->getLinkedProductId()]['position'] = $link->getPosition();
$itsProducts[] = $link->getLinkedProductId();

$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') ;//getting product model

$_product = $model->load($link->getLinkedProductId()); 
//getting product object for particular product id

//echo $_product->getShortDescription(); //product's short description
//echo $_product->getDescription(); // product's long description
//echo $_product->getName(); //product name
//echo $_product->getPrice(); //product's regular Price
//echo $_product->getSpecialPrice(); //product's special Price
//echo $_product->getProductUrl(); //product url
//echo $_product->getImageUrl(); //product's image url
//echo $_product->getSmallImageUrl(); //product's small image url
//echo $_product->getThumbnailUrl(); //product's thumbnail image url  ?>

<li class="item">
<div class="product">
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $_product->getImageUrl(); ?>"
width="110" height="110" alt="1"/>    </a>
<div class="product-details">
<h2 class="product-name-related">
<a title="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>"href="
<?php echo  $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a><div class="price-box">
<?php echo '$'.number_format($_product->getPrice(),2); ?></div></h2>
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('
<?php echo  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>')"
title="Add to  Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php
$bk++;
}
}    
?>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @PrinceKumar - If it works please accept my answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Remove the reference to the block related_products from view.phtml

```
<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>
```

Then add this to anywhere you want in view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('catalog.product.related'); ?>
```

Comment: can we set template path here ?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

under the

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

like below in the `catalog.xml`

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

The rest looks fine. Clear the cache and see if it works

**Edit**: I suggest not to edit the `catalog.xml` file, instead create a `local.xml` file in your `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout` folder and add the code in this file like below

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <remove name="catalog.product.related"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

See [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento) how to create a `local.xml` file

Comment: No it didn't work.it is not calling related.phtml page.nothing is displaying.

Comment: Did you add the block after `<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">` in catalog.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to showcase the related products along with the product view page.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <remove name="catalog.product.related" />
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

then in view.phtml call this

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock(‘catalog.product.related’)->toHtml()
?>
```